# Evaluate different EXPLAINs on Redshift

Tags: explain, redshift

I'm trying to understand EXPLAIN on Redshift. I'm in a case were I have data like this

```
id | user_id | created_at
---|---------------------------------
1  | 1       | 2017-02-08 14:32:10.96
2  | 1       | 2017-02-07 14:32:10.96
3  | 2       | 2017-02-06 14:32:10.96
4  | 2       | 2017-02-05 14:32:10.96
```

I want :

```
id | user_id | created_at
---|---------------------------------
1  | 1       | 2017-02-08 14:32:10.96
3  | 2       | 2017-02-06 14:32:10.96
```

I have this two queries :

```
SELECT id,
       user_id,
       created_at
FROM
  ( SELECT user_id,
           created_at,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                              ORDER BY created_at) AS rownum
   FROM my_table) x
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

With the EXPLAIN  have :

```
XN Subquery Scan x  (cost=1000001263779.68..1000001513986.60 rows=50042 width=16)
  Filter: (rownum = 1)
  ->  XN Window  (cost=1000001263779.68..1000001388883.14 rows=10008277 width=16)
        Partition: user_id
        Order: created_at
        ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000001263779.68..1000001288800.37 rows=10008277 width=16)
              Sort Key: user_id, created_at
              ->  XN Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..100082.77 rows=10008277 width=16)
```

Then the other query :

```
SELECT ac1.user_id, ac1.created_at FROM my_table ac1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) AS MAXDATE
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY user_id
) ac2
ON ac1.user_id = ac2.user_id
AND ac1.created_at = ac2.MAXDATE;
```

And the EXPLAIN :

```
XN Hash Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=150798.74..771939079.62 rows=7257 width=16)
  Hash Cond: (("outer".created_at = "inner".maxdate) AND ("outer".user_id = "inner".user_id))
  ->  XN Seq Scan on my_table ac1  (cost=0.00..100082.77 rows=10008277 width=16)
  ->  XN Hash  (cost=150606.01..150606.01 rows=38548 width=16)
        ->  XN Subquery Scan ac2  (cost=150124.15..150606.01 rows=38548 width=16)
              ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=150124.15..150220.52 rows=38548 width=16)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..100082.77 rows=10008277 width=16)
```

Result are a little bit slower with the first query but I'm lost when I try to understand EXPLAINs. 
It seems that the `cost` is higher on the query that use `ROW_NUMBER()` but that's it same with `rows`.

But what can I extract from those EXPLAINs (I sadly cannot use `ANALYZE` on Redshift)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step in the first query plan that is costly and explains the difference is the sort step on the large number of rows. You are sorting the *entire* dataset (an `O(n log n)` operation, where n is your partition size) so you can then select the first entry. The other rows (#2 - #10,000,000) still had to be sorted even though you never looked at them. On the other hand, max is an `O(n)` operation because you only ever have to keep track of one value as you pass through the data

Answer (score 2):

Fabio has given a great answer.

However for Redshift, it is worth adding that how your data is physically laid out has a dramatic impact on EXPLAIN plan cost.

Create some dummy data: 

(inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667215/redshift-how-can-i-generate-a-series-of-numbers-without-creating-a-table-called)

 
`drop table if exists #my_table;
create table #my_table as 
select
    (row_number() over (order by 1)) - 1 as user_id
    ,(current_date - user_id::int)::timestamp created_at
from
    stl_load_errors
limit 24`

Reproduce similar EXPLAIN plans to the question:

`explain 
SELECT user_id,
       created_at
FROM
  ( SELECT user_id,
           created_at,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                              ORDER BY created_at) AS rownum
   FROM #my_table) x
WHERE rownum = 1`


EXPLAIN:
`XN Subquery Scan x  (cost=1000000000000.79..1000000000001.39 rows=1 width=16)
  Filter: (rownum = 1)
  ->  XN Window  (cost=1000000000000.79..1000000000001.09 rows=24 width=16)
        Partition: user_id
        Order: created_at
        ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000000000000.79..1000000000000.85 rows=24 width=16)
              Sort Key: user_id, created_at
              ->  XN Network  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=24 width=16)
                    Distribute
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on "#my_table"  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=24 width=16)`


Next:

`explain 
SELECT ac1.user_id, ac1.created_at FROM #my_table ac1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) AS MAXDATE
   FROM #my_table
   GROUP BY user_id
) ac2
ON ac1.user_id = ac2.user_id
AND ac1.created_at = ac2.MAXDATE`

EXPLAIN:
`XN Hash Join DS_DIST_INNER  (cost=0.72..822858.77 rows=13 width=16)
  Inner Dist Key: ac1.user_id
  Hash Cond: (("outer".maxdate = "inner".created_at) AND ("outer".user_id = "inner".user_id))
  ->  XN Subquery Scan ac2  (cost=0.36..0.66 rows=24 width=16)
        ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=0.36..0.42 rows=24 width=16)
              ->  XN Seq Scan on "#my_table"  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=24 width=16)
  ->  XN Hash  (cost=0.24..0.24 rows=24 width=16)
        ->  XN Seq Scan on "#my_table" ac1  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=24 width=16)`

This is indeed much faster but data is distributed between nodes (DB_DIST_INNER).

### Now try:

`drop table #my_table_dist;
create table #my_table_dist 
distkey(user_id) sortkey(user_id,created_at) as 
select
    (row_number() over (order by 1)) - 1 as user_id
    ,(current_date - user_id::int)::timestamp created_at
from
    stl_load_errors
limit 24`

Now run EXPLAIN:

`explain 
SELECT user_id,
       created_at
FROM
  ( SELECT user_id,
           created_at,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                              ORDER BY created_at) AS rownum
   FROM #my_table_dist) x
WHERE rownum = 1`

EXPLAIN:
`XN Subquery Scan x  (cost=0.00..0.78 rows=1 width=16)
  Filter: (rownum = 1)
  ->  XN Window  (cost=0.00..0.48 rows=24 width=16)
        Partition: user_id
        Order: created_at
        ->  XN Seq Scan on "#my_table_dist"  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=24 width=16)`

 The data is already sorted and distributed so Redshift simply reads off the answer.

Whilst:

`explain 
SELECT ac1.user_id, ac1.created_at FROM #my_table ac1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) AS MAXDATE
   FROM #my_table_dist
   GROUP BY user_id
) ac2
ON ac1.user_id = ac2.user_id
AND ac1.created_at = ac2.MAXDATE`

EXPLAIN: 
`XN Hash Join DS_DIST_INNER  (cost=0.36..822858.77 rows=13 width=16)
  Inner Dist Key: ac1.user_id
  Hash Cond: (("outer".maxdate = "inner".created_at) AND ("outer".user_id = "inner".user_id))
  ->  XN Subquery Scan ac2  (cost=0.00..0.66 rows=24 width=16)
        ->  XN GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..0.42 rows=24 width=16)
              ->  XN Seq Scan on "#my_table_dist"  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=24 width=16)
  ->  XN Hash  (cost=0.24..0.24 rows=24 width=16)
        ->  XN Seq Scan on "#my_table" ac1  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=24 width=16)`

Note no difference in cost due to distribution of data between nodes (DB_DIST_INNER).